# parse error in let binding: missing required 'in'

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I was solving a problem where is needed to split a full binary tree into a matching duble of binary tree and leaf tree, like:

```
splitFTree :: (FTree a b)  -> (BTree a, LTree b)
```

where

```
data FTree a b = Leaf b | No a (FTree a b) (FTree a b)
data BTree a = Empty | Node a (BTree a) (BTree a)
data LTree a = Tip a | Fork (LTree a) (LTree a)
```

And my solution to this was the next code:

```
splitFTree :: (FTree a b)  -> (BTree a, LTree b)
splitFTree (Leaf a) = ( Node a Empty Empty , Tip a )
splitFTree (No a e d) = let (b1,l1) = splitFTree e
                            (b2,l2) = splitFTree d 
                        in  (Node a b1 b2 , Fork l1 l2)
```

While compiling with GHCI i get the following error, that I do not know how where i got wrong:

```
solucaoficha9.hs:89:25:
parse error in let binding: missing required 'in'
```

Can someone help me about this?

Comment: Can't reproduce this error with your code, but there is another error: http://rextester.com/MRV79991

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already discovered the answer since the `let` and `in` statement must be lined up by the same TAB column on the code, SPACE lining is not enough.